# Edit Scale Object in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to edit a scale group, but when I edit of Vlans it returns an exception. This is the code I've tested. The way of editing is same as creating object, but I've added groupId and policyId along with editObject(). Please let me know if found any doubt. Thank you

```
    RestApiClient client = getSoftlayerClient();
    groupService = Group.service(client, group.getGroupId());

    /**
     * Network Vlans
     */
    Long[] networkVlans = { group.getPublicVlanId(), group.getPrivateVlanId() };

    /**
     * Define SoftLayer_Scale_Group object that you wish to create
     */
    Group templateObject = new Group();
    templateObject.setName(group.getGroupName());
    templateObject.setRegionalGroupId(group.getRegionId());
    templateObject.setTerminationPolicyId(group.gettPolicyId());

    // Unit : SEC, MIN, HOUR, DAY
    templateObject.setCooldown(getSec(group.getCooldownPeriod(), group.getCooldownUnit()));

    templateObject.setMaximumMemberCount(group.getMaxMember());
    templateObject.setMinimumMemberCount(group.getMinMember());

    templateObject.setSuspendedFlag(false);

    // Define SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest
    Guest virtualGuestMemberTemplate = new Guest();
    virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setHostname(group.getHostName());
    virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setDomain(group.getDomain());
    virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setMaxMemory(group.getMaxMemory());
    virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setStartCpus(group.getStartCpu());

    List<AutoScaleStorageVO> storageList = group.getStorageList();

    for (AutoScaleStorageVO storage : storageList) {
        Device block = new Device();
        block.setDevice(storage.getDiskOrder());
        Image image = new Image();
        image.setCapacity(storage.getCapacity());
        block.setDiskImage(image);
        virtualGuestMemberTemplate.getBlockDevices().add(block);
    }

    // Define Location

    if (group.getDatacenter() != "") {
        Location location = new Location();
        location.setName(group.getDatacenter());
        virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setDatacenter(location);
    }

    // Define Hourly billing and local disk
    virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setHourlyBillingFlag(true);
    if (storageList.get(0).getDiskType().equals("LOCAL")) {
        virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setLocalDiskFlag(true);
    } else {
        virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setLocalDiskFlag(false);
    }

    // Network Components
    Component networkComponent = new Component();
    networkComponent.setMaxSpeed(group.getMaxSpeed());

    virtualGuestMemberTemplate.getNetworkComponents().add(networkComponent);

    // OS
    virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setOperatingSystemReferenceCode(group.getOsCode());

    virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setPrivateNetworkOnlyFlag(group.isPrivateOnly());

    // Ssh key
    if (group.getSshKeyId() != null) {
        Key newKey = new Key();
        newKey.setId(group.getSshKeyId());
        virtualGuestMemberTemplate.getSshKeys().add(newKey);
    }

    // Provision Script
    if (group.getPostInstallUri() != "") {
        virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setPostInstallScriptUri(group.getPostInstallUri());
    }

    // Network Vlans : Edit vlans with new vlanIds.

        for (int i = 0; i <= networkVlans.length; i++) {
            Vlan vlan = new Vlan();
            vlan.setNetworkVlanId(networkVlans[i]);
            templateObject.getNetworkVlans().add(vlan);
        }

    // Adding Virtual Guest member template to the template
    templateObject.setVirtualGuestMemberTemplate(virtualGuestMemberTemplate);

Boolean result = groupService.editObject(templateObject);
```

20:43:21.814 [http-bio-8181-exec-2] ERROR - Failed to Edit autoscale group  Exception : 2

Comment: when you copy your code, please at least add your imports I do not know what packages you are using I waste a lot time trying to figure out it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.softlayer.api.*;
import com.softlayer.api.service.scale.network.Vlan;
import com.softlayer.api.service.scale.Group;


public class EditScale {

    private static String user = "set me";

    private static String apiKey = "set me";

    private static ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(user, apiKey).withLoggingEnabled();

    private static Long idScaleGroup = new Long(11111);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Group.Service scaleGroupService = Group.service(client, idScaleGroup);
        scaleGroupService.setMask("mask[networkVlans]");


        Group scaleGroupEdit = scaleGroupService.getObject();

        for(Vlan v:scaleGroupEdit.getNetworkVlans()){
            Vlan.Service vlanService = Vlan.service(client, v.getId() );
            vlanService.deleteObject();
        }

        Vlan.Service vlanService = Vlan.service(client);

        Vlan templateObjectPrivate = new Vlan();
        templateObjectPrivate.setScaleGroupId(scaleGroupEdit.getId());
        templateObjectPrivate.setNetworkVlanId(2222222L);
        Vlan vlanPrivate = vlanService.createObject(templateObjectPrivate);

        Vlan templateObjectPublic = new Vlan();
        templateObjectPublic.setScaleGroupId(scaleGroupEdit.getId());
        templateObjectPublic.setNetworkVlanId(333333L);
        Vlan vlanPublic = vlanService.createObject(templateObjectPublic);

        List<Vlan> vlans = new ArrayList<Vlan>();
        vlans.add(vlanPrivate);
        vlans.add(vlanPublic);

        scaleGroupEdit.getNetworkVlans().clear();
        scaleGroupEdit.getNetworkVlans().addAll(vlans);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(scaleGroupService.editObject(scaleGroupEdit)));

    }

}
```

Comment: I posted a runnable code, but it still returns errors.